# Django Huey Crontab every day at 10am

Tags: django, python-huey

I'm using Django 4.0.4 and huey 2.4.3. What I would like to atchieve it's to run a task everyday at 10am, using a periodic task.

**My task folder path => project/apps/utils/tasks**

```
+-- project/
|   +-- apps/
|       +-- utils/
|           +-- tasks/
|               +--__init__.py
|               +--sms_task.py
|               +--tasks.py
```

**In the **init**.py file in tasks folder I've imported all tasks:**

```
__all__ = ["tasks", "sms_task"]
```

**Here my Huey Config in settings.py file:**

```
    HUEY = {
    'huey_class': 'huey.RedisHuey',  # Huey implementation to use.
    'name': 'ASISPO',  # Name of the Redis connection.
    'immediate': False,
    'connection': {
        'url': env('REDIS_URL', default=None),  # Allow Redis config via a DSN.
    },
    'consumer': {
        'blocking': True,
        'loglevel': True,
        'workers': 8,  # Number of consumer workers.
        'scheduler_interval': 1,  # Check schedule every second, -s.
        'health_check_interval': 5,  # Check worker health every second.
        'simple_log': True,
        },
    }
```

**What I've done so far in my tasks.py file:**

```
@periodic_task(crontab(hour='10'))
def getjplus1():
    calculation = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    filter_fields = {
        'date_ope': calculation,
        'escalade': 'False',
        'rel_dou': 'False',
        'rel_dou_ok':'False',
        'rel_hemo':'False',
        'rel_hemo_ok':'False'
        }
    for key, value in filter_fields.items():
        suivis_patient = SuiviPatient.objects.filter(
            response_suivi_patient__suivi_field_name__icontains=key ,
            response_suivi_patient__response__icontains=value, 
            status='planifié',
            archived=False
            )
    
    get_suivi_patient_j1(list(set(suivis_patient)))
```

But it's not running at 10am.

**however it works when I run periodic_task every minute like so:**

```
@periodic_task(crontab(minute="*/1"))
def getjplus1():
    calculation = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    filter_fields = {
        'date_ope': calculation,
        'escalade': 'False',
        'rel_dou': 'False',
        'rel_dou_ok':'False',
        'rel_hemo':'False',
        'rel_hemo_ok':'False'
        }
    for key, value in filter_fields.items():
        suivis_patient = SuiviPatient.objects.filter(
            response_suivi_patient__suivi_field_name__icontains=key ,
            response_suivi_patient__response__icontains=value, 
            status='planifié',
            archived=False
            )
    
    get_suivi_patient_j1(list(set(suivis_patient))
```

)

Comment: Check out your timezones, it may be running at 10am UTC when you intend to run at 10am local time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you are using `huey` package as part of your code. You can utilize its `periodic_task` decorator and add crontab within it.

```
from huey import crontab

@huey.periodic_task(crontab(hour='10'))
def every_ten_in_the_morning():
    print('This task runs every 10 in the morning.')
```

You can also check its documentation to know more about huey periodic task : https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#periodic-tasks

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've tried to add hour='10' in crontab but it's not seem to work.
however it works when I run periodic_task every minute like so: @periodic_task(crontab(minute="*/1"))

Comment: Setting the hour to 10 will only run during 10 am in the morning. Did you check it during that time?

Comment: There may be a discrepancy between your timezone and UTC. Check trouble-shooting guide https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html - it describes this exact situation.

Answer (score -3):

For this you can use via `pip install django-celery` and use celery.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=10, minute=0))
def every_day():
    print("This is run every Monday morning at 10:00")
```

Comment: More like smellery